# Create an isometric projection of a Landscape image

Tags: gimp, isometric

I have an image of my college, how can I convert this image to an isometric projection like effect using Gimp or Inkscape.

**Source Image:**

[image: College]

**Desired Effect:**

[image: Isometric Effect]

Comment: You can not. However if you have that as a 3D model then yes that can be done.

Comment: Clearly that isn't a photograph but a 3D model.  So if you can get access to the original 3D files, you might be able to open them and convert them into an isometric view.  GIMP and Inkscape are not 3D modelling applications. Blender(dot)org is what you need if you want Open Source 3D software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the school is seen from too low and maybe from not from the wanted geographic direction. I think this would be a perfect test work just in that school to find those who cannot solve technical problems.

Technically easily the problem is solvable in 2 ways:

- take a new photo (obviously the photo is not taken from air, the target seems to be a miniature)
- get a 3D model of the target and adjust the viewing direction

In 2D software the task is magnificient - even, if only the viewing altitude is changed. You must make every horizontal surface higher and every vertical surface lower. In addition the skewings of the objects change. Inkscape nor GIMP have no idea what different parts need, because for them all is flat.

Do not know, how to get a 3D model or a miniature to be photographed and must get the job done or get fired? There's a straw that can prevent you to be drowned. Google can have enough stuff for you to construct the needed 3D info by yourself. The satellite image shows the real horizontal positions of the buildings, roads and other big objects. Compare it numerically with your current photo. Then you know what is the viewing angle there. You can calculate how much all should be stretched or compressed in your current image.

I have got a medieval castle from there as a ready to use SketchUP 3D model. Only the oldest part was as 3D, but there were plenty of photos, the street view and a perfectly flat, but accurate enough satellite image of the numerous auxiliary buildings.The customer wanted an aerial photo-like illustration where all was seen from east. All available aerial photos were taken from south, west or north.

Check also SketchUP 3D warehouse. It's now kept by Trimble.

Comment: @Aswin Mohan Can you possibly reveal how you did solve the case? I bet  interested persons exist here and there.